# Apache2 LinuxMint Lararvel

Tags: php, linux, laravel, apache2, virtualhost

I configure apache virtual host linked project in laravel.
But I guess autoloader not work.
This is my situation.

In /etc/apache2/sites-avaible in wrote my file for virtualhost (I tried yet <VirtualHost *:80> and not work).

```
<VirtualHost medfx.lo:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@medfx.lo
    DocumentRoot /var/www/medfx/public

    <Directory "/var/www/medfx/public">
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        ReWriteEngine On
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I /var/www/  I create my project medfx and create laravel project.

```
root@tecnico57-System-Product-Name:/var/www/medfx# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1686 ott  5 12:43 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1827 ott  5 12:43 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 302152 ott  5 14:29 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    767 ott  5 12:43 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 776150 ott  5 12:43 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1202 ott  5 12:43 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 public
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3810 ott  5 12:43 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 routes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    563 ott  5 12:43 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 ott  5 12:43 tests
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root   4096 ott  5 14:29 vendor
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    520 ott  5 12:43 webpack.mix.js
```

Now, if I go on http://medfx.lo, it is view :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   tecnico57-System-Product-Name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Anyone can help me?

Best regards.

Comment: My file in /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable is "medfx.lo.conf"

Comment: have you enabled the vhost/site? e.g.: ```a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/medfx.lo.conf``` or ```ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/medfx.lo.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/medfx.lo.conf```

Comment: Yes, it's already enabled. I should find in /etc/hosts, my virtual host?
Now, hosts is this:

127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      tecnico57-System-Product-Name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: no, not ```/etc/hosts```, but have the ```medfx.lo.conf``` been softlinked to ```/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/```?

Comment: Yes, it's been softlinked after execute a2ensite medfx.lo.conf.
I guess the virtual host is correct, but not interpreted index.php and so not load project

Answer (score 0):

The solution is PHP. Apache2 not interpreted Laravel project, don't run correctly php and it's print code to screen without interprete.

Solution is reinstall global php and link apache2 to new version php. Leave code.

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.1

sudo apt-get install php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-json php7.1-opcache php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-zip php7.1-fpm

sudo a2dismod php7.2

sudo a2enmod php7.1

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Use your prefer version php in command before run it.

Best regards
Ty Kristian anyways !